# Antique table that has gaps in the wood

Tags: glue

Can you paint over titebond 2? I'm working on a project that I can't clamp the boards together. There about 1/4 inches apart. I used a ton of glue, and made a big mess!

Comment: Welcome to WSE.  You can paint over dried glue successfully, but you may see textures telegraph through.  You cannot stain since the stain will not penetrate through the glue.

Comment: A 1/4" gap filled with glue will be very weak. FYI with an adhesive like Titebond only tight glue joints are strong — from hairline thickness to invisibly thin is what you're aiming for. Strongly advise you take the thing apart and do it again properly! We should be able to advise on all aspects of the repair if needed, including on how to clamp without shop-bought clamps.

Comment: Sounds like an answer @Ashlar

Comment: If you know that your project will have gaps you should not be using a glue like titebond.  Wood glues do not have significant strength when spanning gaps. 
 Instead you should use a good 2-part epoxy, like West or Entropy, with an appropriate filler material.

Answer (score 2):

You can paint over dried glue successfully, but you may see textures telegraph through. You cannot stain since the stain will not penetrate through the glue.